# Copy element with attributes but without child elements

Tags: xml, xslt, copy

With the following xml document

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<a name="john">
   <b/>
</a>
```

and the following xslt

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="a">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><a/>
```

What i want is `<a name="John"/>`. How do i get the element `a` along with its attribute `name` **and** without its child `b`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the attributes as well:

```
<xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```